# Ionic: From iOS to Android: Compilation error with whitelist plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing am app that works great for iOS, using ionic. 
In trying to test for Android for the first time by doing `ionic build android` and it compiled fine. When I installed it on my android device, I noticed all network access was prohibited. On further investigation, I read I needed to add the whitelist plugin

The steps I followed:

```
ionic ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

(at my project root)
Then, I added the following to config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
```

When I do an ionic build android, I now get a compilation error:

```
projects/phonegap/zmNinja/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/whitelist/WhitelistPlugin.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method parse(android.content.Context)
location: class org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin.CustomConfigXmlParser
        new CustomConfigXmlParser().parse(context);
```

Incidentally, I also get various warnings (which occurred before as well, but did not affect app compilation) of the sort:

```
 major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

Can someone advice on how I fix that parsing error? I'm very new to Android with ionic.

Info:

```
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.1
Cordova CLI: 4.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.3.18
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.1 Build version 6D1002 
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
ios-deploy version: Not installed
```

I also have Android SDK version 21 & 22 installed. I believe cordova needs 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - looks like it was a crosswalk issue with Cordova version. I updated cordova to 5, updated the ionic cli, removed the crosswalk plugin, compiled to make sure it works, then added it back again and everything worked. Sometimes a "reboot" does help